# SwiftUI image in view not updating after fetching data from firebase

Tags: firebase, swiftui, fetch

After I add a post with an image and I go back to the main feed view, I can see the post info(username, upload date etc.); but instead of an image, there is only a gap.

After I go to another tab and come back to Main Feed View, I can see the image then. Why I can't fetch the image and update the UI immediately?

this is the FeedCellView

```
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct FeedCell: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: FeedCellViewModel

    @EnvironmentObject var auth: AuthViewModel
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var didLike: Bool { return viewModel.post.didLike ?? false }
    
    @State var showActionSheet = false
    
    init(viewModel: FeedCellViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // user info
            HStack {
                if let user = viewModel.post.user{
                    NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView(user: user)){
                        KFImage(URL(string: viewModel.post.ownerImageUrl))
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                            .clipped()
                            .cornerRadius(18)
                        
                       
                        Text(viewModel.post.ownerUsername)
                            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold))
                    }
                }
              
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 8)
            .padding(.leading, 8)
            .padding(.trailing, 12)
            
            // post image
            KFImage(URL(string: viewModel.post.imageUrl))
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 4, alignment: .center)
                .frame(maxHeight: 440)
                .clipped()
                .padding(.leading, 2)
            
            // action buttons
            HStack(spacing: 16) {
                Button(action: {
                    didLike ? viewModel.unlike() : viewModel.like()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: didLike ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .foregroundColor(didLike ? .red : .black)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .padding(4)
                })
                
                NavigationLink(destination: CommentsView(post: viewModel.post)) {
                    Image(systemName: "bubble.right")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .padding(4)
                }
                
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .padding(4)
                })
            }
            .padding(.leading, 4)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            
            // caption
            
            Text(viewModel.likeString)
                .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold))
                .padding(.leading, 8)
                .padding(.bottom, 0.5)
//            
            HStack {
                Text(viewModel.post.ownerUsername).font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold)) +
                    Text(" \(viewModel.post.caption)")
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
            }.padding(.horizontal, 8)
            
            Text(viewModel.timestampString)
                .font(.system(size: 14))
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .padding(.leading, 8)
                .padding(.top, -2)
        }
    }
    
    func  getActionSheet() -> ActionSheet{
        return ActionSheet(title: Text("What would you like to do?"), message: nil, buttons: [
            .destructive(Text("Delete"), action: {
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    viewModel.deletePost()
                }
                
            }),
            
            .default(Text("Learn more..."), action: {
                print("LEARN MORE PRESSED")
            }),
            
            .cancel()
        ])
    }
}

struct FeedCell_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FeedCell(viewModel: FeedCellViewModel(post: postExample))
    }
}
```

this is the viewModel

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class FeedCellViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var post: Post
    
    var likeString: String{
        let label = post.likes == 1 ? "like" : "likes"
        return "\(post.likes) \(label)"
    }
    
    var timestampString: String{
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth]
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        return formatter.string(from: post.timestamp.dateValue(), to: Date()) ?? ""
    }
    
    init(post: Post){
        self.post = post
        checkIfUserLikedPost()
        fetchPostUser()
    }
    
    func like(){
        guard let uid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else {return}
        guard let postId = post.id else {return}
        Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(post.id ?? "").collection("post-likes").document(uid).setData([:]){_ in
            Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).collection("user-likes").document(postId).setData([:]){ _ in
                
                Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(postId).updateData(["likes": self.post.likes + 1])
                NotificationsViewModel.uploadNotification(toUid: self.post.ownerUid, type: .like, post: self.post)
                self.post.didLike = true
                self.post.likes += 1
            }
        }
    }
    
    func unlike(){
        guard post.likes > 0 else {return}
        guard let uid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else {return}
        guard let postId = post.id else {return}
        Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(post.id ?? "").collection("post-likes").document(uid).delete{_ in
            Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).collection("user-likes").document(postId).delete{ _ in
                
                Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(postId).updateData(["likes": self.post.likes - 1])
                self.post.didLike = false
                self.post.likes -= 1
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func checkIfUserLikedPost(){
        guard let uid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else {return}
        guard let postId = post.id else {return}
        
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).collection("user-likes").document(postId).getDocument{ snapshot, _ in
            guard let didLike = snapshot?.exists else {return}
            self.post.didLike = didLike
        }
    }
    
    func deletePost(){
        guard let postId = post.id else {return}

        Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(postId).delete()
    }
    
    func fetchPostUser(){

        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(post.ownerUid).getDocument { snapshot, _ in
            self.post.user = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add `.id(viewModel.post.ownerImageUrl)` to your `KFImage` does it work?

Comment: I get the ownerImage right away, the postImage is the problem. So it shouldn't be a kingfisher issue

Comment: Sorry -- couldn't tell which one was the issue (lots of code there). I stand by my comment about applying an id, though, if you haven't tried it. I've been surprised before about what will/won't force KF to update.

Comment: I have the same problem, image does not update when the binding URL changes. It just goes blank, in my case it displays the place holder. But if I tap back and open the screen again, the image is there. Not sure where the problem is yet.